# Разница между vh vw и % ,что лучше?

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Разница между vh vw и % ,видел в интернете ,но не уловил сути,что лучше использовать vw или % для размеров и лучше для чего именно его использовать,для каких тегов или блоков?

Comment: Когда уместно и удобно в решаемой задаче, тогда и использовать, ваш кэп

Answer (score 7, accepted):

% используется в соотношении к родителю. 
Vw/vh независимо от родителя всегда на всю ширину/высоту экрана.
Пример:

```css
.block{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.block__item{
  height: 100px;
  
}
.block__item_percent{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.block__item_vw{
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item block__item_percent">
    
  </div>
  <div class="block__item block__item_vw">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ааа,благодарю,я понял)
Но для каких элементов лучше заадавать vw?
Для фона?или может конкретных блоков?
Просто процент кажется удобнее в этом плане,да,я понял,что это немного разные вещи,но все же)

Comment: @KsivilianYavorskii, я обычно задаю для фиксированных элементов. Header, overlay. Иногда для body задаю, если создаю странички без скролла.

Comment: @KsivilianYavorskii, 
P.s если ответ вам помог и вы считаете,что вы решили свою проблему, отметьте его правильным)

Comment: Та я бы рад,но мне пишет система,что я нуб и у меня меньше 15 репутации,я не так давно здесь зарегистрировался)
Как будет возможность обязательно вернусь и нажму лайк)
Еще раз спасибо)

К стати задал для body 100vw и появился боковой скрол,а при 100% его нет,чего так?

Comment: @KsivilianYavorskii, добавьте body{margin:0;}